# Help regarding rEFInd

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, refind

I have a Macbook Pro and I am in the process of trying to create a triple boot with Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS. Using the disk utility in OSX to create the other two partitions and rEFInd to work as my boot manager but I have run into some difficulties. I installed the rEFInd manager via `./install.sh` and I would like to customize the theme but I cannot locate the file EFI in my Macintosh HD location. Any advice? I am also new to trying to create a triple boot so any other additional information would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you used `install.sh`, without any options, to install rEFInd from OS X, then the rEFInd binary and support files ended up on your [EFI System Partition (ESP),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) which OS X does not mount by default. Given your plans, the easiest way to access it is to wait until after you install Ubuntu. If you install Ubuntu in EFI mode, the ESP will be mounted at `/boot/efi`, and rEFInd will be in `/boot/efi/EFI/refind`. You should have no problems modifying the files from Ubuntu, although you'll need to use `sudo` to do anything with those files.

Alternatively, you can mount the ESP in OS X. There are several ways to do this; one is:

```
mkdir /Volumes/ESP
sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 /Volumes/ESP
```

Note that this example assumes that your ESP is `/dev/disk0s1`, which is the default location for the ESP on Mac systems. If you've repartitioned your disk from scratch with non-Apple software, it might be somewhere else. You can check with `diskutil`, `gdisk`, `parted`, GParted, or other tools to be sure you're using the right partition. (OS X's Disk Utility deliberately hides the ESP, though, so it's useless for this task.) Once you mount the ESP like this, rEFInd will be in `/Volumes/ESP/EFI/refind`.

One more point: Before proceeding with your Windows installation, you may want to read [this question and its answers.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655495/windows-8-installer-complains-about-mbr-partitions-but-i-dont-see-any) If you created any FAT partitions with Disk Utility, that tool probably turned your disk into a [hybrid MBR,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html) which is an ugly and dangerous hack used by Apple to enable BIOS-mode booting of Windows. This might indeed be necessary, but Windows 8 and later often boot fine in EFI mode on Macs, and to do this, the disk must *not* have a hybrid MBR. Understanding the interactions between boot mode (EFI vs. BIOS) and partition table type (straight GPT, GPT with hybrid MBR, and straight MBR) will help you keep your hair as you set up a triple-boot on a Mac.

Comment: i recently re-installed rEFInd using 'sudo install.sh' and it seems that my computer created a '/Volumes/ESP/EFI folder/refind', i had it before but when i tried to customize the theme it still loaded as boot manager but didn't show up in the same folder. Do you know how to customize the boot manager by changing the background images and icons correctly? I checked out rodsbooks.com/refind/themes.html. but I am still a little confused on how to apply the changes that i wanted to create.

Comment: The `install.sh` script mounts the ESP, much as I described in my post. It leaves the ESP mounted in that way, but when you reboot, it will be unmounted, so to access the ESP (and rEFInd files with it), you must re-mount the ESP. This, however, is *in OS X.* As this is an Ubuntu forum, the answer in Ubuntu is to access the ESP from `/boot/efi`, as I described in my answer. See [here](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Basics_of_partitions,_filesystems,_mount_points) or do a Web search to learn more about mounting partitions. (The principles apply to both OS X and Linux, but details differ.)